# inject sencha panel inside HTML div

Tags: html, sencha-touch-2, panel

I have a panel inside a view

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.myPanel', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
xtype : 'myPanel',

config : {
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    html : '<div class="body"><div class="title">My Page</div><div class="content"></div></div>'
}
});
```

Is there a way I can add another panel inside the `<div class="content"></div>`?

I need to add this panel between the content div tags:

```
var pan = Ext.define('My.view.otherView', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
xtype : 'otherView',
config : {
    title : '<img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"/>',
    scrollable: false,
    width: '100%',
    cls : 'panicView',
    layout: 'vbox',
    items : [
                {
                    flex : 1,
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: '<img class="pageHeaderImage" src="images/Header.png" /><div class="pageHeader">Emergency!</div>'
                },
                {
                    flex : 6,
                    xtype: 'formGrid'
                }
            ]
}
});
```

IS there a way that this can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to add a panel into a div using its class.

```
Ext.application({
    name: ('SF' || 'SenchaFiddle'),

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyApp.view.firstpage', {
            extend: 'Ext.Panel',
            xtype: 'firstcontainer',            
            config: {     
                fullscreen:true,
                title: 'Setting',
                iconCls: 'settings',
                html: [
                    '<div class="container">', 
                    '</div>'].join("")
            }
        });
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.firstpage');
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{html:'Container Inner Panel'
                ,renderTo:Ext.DomQuery.select('.container')[0]});
    }
});
```

[Here is the link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/Z3WBp/).